# I cannot display data form an API using v-for in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, v-for

I cannot get or display data from an API but the API is working fine when I console.log the issue. but I cannot display data in my table I used v-for I am new to Vue.js I don't know how to solve this issue

I am using Vue.js 2, Axios method to connect to my API

here's my code

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default{
  data(){
    return{
      errorMessage: "",
      successMessage: "",
      users: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.getAllUsers();
  },
  methods:{
    getAllUsers: function(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:8888/vue-and-php/public/api/config.php?action=read', { crossdomain: true })
      .then(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        if(response.data.error){
          app.errorMessage = response.data.message;
        }else{
          app.users = response.data.users;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY MY DATA

```
                <!--test PHP-->
                  <button class="fright addNew btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Add New</button>
                  <p class="errorMessage alert alert-danger" v-if="errorMessage">
                    {{errorMessage}}
                  </p>
                  <p class="successMessage alert alert-success" v-if="successMessage">
                    {{successMessage}}
                  </p>
                  <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>User Name</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Edit</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="user in users">
                      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">ADD</button></td>
                      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">DELETE</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Comment: Why do you set the response to `app.users`? I would expect `this.users`...

Comment: I assume you are able to log `response.data.message`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do

```
app.users = response.data.users;
```

Since app is not defined anywhere and your browsers console must be throwing an error, what are trying to do over here is assigning the users you have defined in data function.

That users object is present in current context and can be accessed through 'this' keyword.

Try :

```
if(response.data.error){
    this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
}
else{
    this.users = response.data.users;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your time I used your code but with little corrections

this is the final code that works

```
    getAllUsers: function(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:8888/vue-and-php/public/api/config.php?action=read', { crossdomain: true })
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response);
        if(response.data.error){
          this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
        }else{
          this.users = response.data.users;
        }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set some information into your `users` data field. You need to do something like:

```
if (response.data.error) {
    this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
} else {
    this.users = response.data.users;
}
```

**Explanation**: Vue reacts to changes in `data` and `props`. By doing `this.users = response.data.users`, you are telling Vue that the `users` have changed and then Vue will re-render based on how you've used `users` inside your template.

Comment: Thank you for your time 

but I did exactly what you said but I am getting errors it says "Faq.vue?2d60:172 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'users' of undefined
    at eval (Faq.vue?2d60:172)"

Comment: @BeingMR.G: Probably because you're not binding this with your method.

Try and prefer this:
`
getAllUsers() {...}
`
instead of
`
getAllUsers: function(){
`